# Who is responsible for maintaining the child(ren) if a wife gets pregnant in nikah mut'ah?

Tags: shiism, nikah-al-mutah, pregnancy

If a husband and wife are married as per [nikah mut'ah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikah_mut%E2%80%98ah), it's possible the wife could become pregnant.  This seems to open up a host of complications with regards to maintenance and custody.  Google reveals anti-mut'ah web pages and isn't much help.  However, I found this:

> A woman with whom temporary marriage is contracted, is not entitled to subsistence even if she becomes pregnant. -- [Ayatollah Sistani](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2350/)

This leaves open the responsibility for the child(ren).

**Question**: Who is responsible for maintaining the child(ren) if a wife gets pregnant in nikah mut'ah?

Comment: @Casanova I think it will be best if this answered from a Shia point of view as Sunnis don't allow nikah  mut'ah.

Comment: @Armaan Yeah that is why I didn't answer.

Comment: The husband is responsible for maintaining the child. The same rules regarding a child apply as in permanent marriage. When I've found the reference I will answer properly, inshAllah.

Comment: Why Sunnis don't allow nikah mut'ah?

Answer (score 2):

> Who is responsible for that?

According to Islam (Shia Islam), in such case, the father is responsible for maintaining (giving alimony and ...) the child(ren) if a wife gets pregnant in Nikah Mut'ah.

More explanation:

From the Islamic viewpoint, he or she (the child) will be recognized as their kids and they'll be regarded as his or her lawful father and mother, therefore the child’s nafaqah/sustenance will be the duty of the father and actually the child will inherit from both his mother/father.

> As a result the child will never feel ashamed/humiliated; because
>   his/her mother and father have obeyed Allah by being in a relationship
>   validated both by Islam and law instead of committing anything against
>   the shariah (Islamic law). However we should be aware that the
>   responsibility for taking care of the child is not only given to the
>   father in temporary marriage but also in permanent marriage. In both
>   cases, it is the mother’s right to take care of the child, for two
>   years if it were a boy, and seven years if it were a girl[4], which
>   she can give up to the father or use, but after that certain period
>   this right will be passed on to the father...

To read the complete text, refer to:

- http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa3354

Answer (score 0):

What is the position of children born from Mut’ah?
There is no difference between the children of Nikah or Mut’ah. Both are considered legitimate under the Shari’ah – they inherit from their parents, and all Islamic laws apply with regards to paternity.

Source: [www.shiapen.com](http://www.shiapen.com/comprehensive/mutah/what-is-mutah-2.html)

Comment: Please provide evidence to support your answer (see the [how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) guide). The link you provided to ShiaPen is an unattributed article, and it does not provide evidence as to the position of children born from _Mut'ah_.